# Is it possible to enable cross domain request using XHR?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I've a server named, `foo.com` where my application is running and accessing a service available on a different domain `bar.foo.com`.

With the simple XHR request to `bar.foo.com/getUsers`, I'm getting an error saying, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`. I do not want to use `JSONP` as a fallback to cross-domain issue.

Is there any easy fix I can do on server level to enable cross subdomain requests while XHRing?

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/server.html. You may want to replace `*` with a stricter set of URLs.

Comment: @Blender: Thats great. Also If I serve an HTML file from `http://bar.foo.com/test.html` in an iframe inside `index.html` page at `http://foo.com/index.html` - Will I be able to access the iframe's body and manipulate it, considering different sub-domains but cors enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I need to set allow-cross-domain headers on server when a response is returned  as [suggested by](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) @Blender above.

Or I can use [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) library which uses PostMessage API to enable cors. With this I can even read iframe's content served by different domain.